# Easiest way to upgrade LibreOffice 4 to 5 on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, updates, libreoffice

Title, pretty much. I currently have LibreOffice 4.2.8.2 on Ubuntu 14.04. I'm just wondering what the easiest way to upgrade to the new LibreOffice 5 is, without creating duplicate applications or screwing everything up. Can anyone give me a quick method? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Those could work I guess. I was kinda hoping for some nice more specific steps to take. Sorta lazy. Sorry if this is a waste of a post

Answer (score 9):

I believe the simplest way would be to follow this [guide](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/07/libreoffice-4-4-5-released-how-to-upgrade/).

Otherwise you can use the *check for update* menu:

https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Check_for_Updates_1

edit:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:libreoffice/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Is that better now? :)